# Nextjs content security policy configuration

Tags: reactjs, cors, next.js13, content-security-policy

i have an issue in configuring next.config with the middleware.js
i setup a i18n it works correctly , when i add csp to the middleware , i can't get blocked by the browser

here is middleware.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { i18n } from "./i18n.config";
import { setNonce } from "@/lib/utils";

import { match as matchLocale } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher";
import Negotiator from "negotiator";

function getLocale(request) {
  const negotiatorHeaders = {};

  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value));

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales = i18n.locales;
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages();

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale);
  return locale;
}

export function middleware(request) {
  const nonce = crypto.randomUUID();
  setNonce(nonce);
  console.log("middlware", nonce);
  const cspHeader = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic';
    style-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}';
    img-src 'self' blob: data:;
    font-src 'self';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'self';
    form-action 'self';
    frame-ancestors 'none';
    block-all-mixed-content;
    upgrade-insecure-requests;
`;

  const requestHeaders = new Headers();
  requestHeaders.set("x-nonce", nonce);
  requestHeaders.set(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    // Replace newline characters and spaces
    cspHeader.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim()
  );

  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  );

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request);
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}`,
        request.url
      )
    );
  }
  return NextResponse.next({
    headers: requestHeaders,
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}

export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: [
    {
      source: "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
      missing: [
        { type: "header", key: "next-router-prefetch" },
        { type: "header", key: "purpose", value: "prefetch" },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

and here is  next.config

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
  images: {
    domains: [""],
  },

  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*", // automatically handles all locales
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Referrer-Policy",
            value: "origin-when-cross-origin",
          },
          {
            key: "X-DNS-Prefetch-Control",
            value: "on",
          },
          {
            key: "X-Frame-Options",
            value: "SAMEORIGIN",
          },
          {
            key: "Permissions-Policy",
            value: "camera=(), microphone=()",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

i get [image]

i expect to have access  but nothing show up i have make console.log to nonce

**page** b0c26aa6-5f70-455a-a81a-2588ef6e58fd
**layout** b0c26aa6-5f70-455a-a81a-2588ef6e58fd
**middlware** 25d65628-2126-44fb-bfa8-023c604535a3
**middlware** e9797733-b9c9-4cb6-8209-ea7b2b396873